# How to Vlook Max value from column E and return adjacent value from column A?

Tags: google-sheets

[image: example]

i have been trying to find the max value and min from column E and return the corresponding stock name from column A in H3 and H4 respectively.

i tried vlook max, not working. tried googling but not getting proper solution. kindly help.

Comment: This can be done with the Filter function `=filter (A:A, E:E=MAX(E:E))`

Comment: @Sergey Hey, Thanks man. Works for both max and min. Thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=FILTER(A:A; E:E=MAX(E:E))
```

or QUERY:

```
=QUERY(A:E; "select A where E = "&MAX(E:E))
```